# Split and store an integer into two byte

Tags: c#

I am working on a Embedded systems and I have only 2 Bytes of storage. I need to store a JSON response in those 2 byte. the JSON response is a string containing 2 digits. How can I convert the string to an unsigned integer split and save into those 2 bytes. I am using C#:

var results = "16";

I need to convert this and store it into 2 bytes.

Comment: `var x = short.Parse(results)`?

Comment: so I have done this operation. a short is  2 byte. I need to be able to split that and save in 2 bytes of data and those bytes are not together. they are apart. so by splitting I can save the data in those 2 Byte slots

Comment: ... followed by `var b1 = (byte)(x & 0xFF); var b2 = (byte)(x >> 8);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good way to convert between short and bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442583/good-way-to-convert-between-short-and-bytes)

Comment: Is your number decimal or hex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @TheBlueOne said - a two digit number, even when hexadecimal requires just 1 byte - but for larger numbers you can use
[BitConverter.GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-5.0).

```
var s2 = "FF01"; 
var n = Convert.ToUInt16(s2, 16); 
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(n);
//bytes[0] = 1
//bytes[1] = 255
```

Answer (score 2):

As your value is only 2 digits long you just need 1 byte to store it.
You can just call Byte.Parse("16") and you will get 16 as a byte.
You can then store your byte whereever you want.